# Vertical column data filling using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Im new to XSLT and My XML is below

```
<Aus>
  <au>
     <ele>
        <auid>Au1</auid>
        <cid>C1</cid>
        <fn>F1</fn>
        <sn>S1</sn>
        <dept>D1</dept>
     </ele>
     
     <ele>
        <auid>Au2</auid>
        <cid>C2</cid>
        <fn>F2</fn>
        <sn>S2</sn>
        <dept>D2</dept>
     </ele>
     
     <ele>
        <auid>Au3</auid>
        <cid>C3</cid>
        <fn>F3</fn>
        <sn>S3</sn>
        <dept>D4</dept>
     </ele>..............
  </au>
</Aus>
```

I want the output like below in html view using XSLT conversion
[image]

but XSLT code should be simple to identify next columns by position increment. Please help me.

My current code is

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Aus/au">
<table>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="ele[1]/auid"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="ele[2]/auid"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="ele[3]/auid"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="ele[1]/cid"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="ele[2]/cid"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="ele[3]/cid"/></td>
</tr>
..........
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Seems like a trivial task. Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: hi michael.hor257k thanks for the question. Now I updated my excepted output and my current code here. it requires manual input to identify and specify the element position in code. Also "n" number of element input not to be specified in code manually.

Comment: I see you have changed your expected result to a **pivoted** table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="Aus/au">
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="ele[1]/*" mode="row"/>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ele/*" mode="row">
      <tr>
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../../ele/*[$pos]"/>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ele/*">
      <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaiK

The sample you linked in your comment seems to have more complex input data as it seems there are nested elements, also there seem to be lots of elements without data; however, the templates could be adapted to e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="authorDetails/authors">
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="element[1]/descendant::*[not(*)]" mode="row"/>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="element//*" mode="row">
      <tr>
          <th>
              <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
          </th>
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::authors/element/descendant::*[not(*)][$pos]"/>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="element//*">
      <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaiK/5

Comment: It not works in my original code for tags under "author details" refer link https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaiK/4

Comment: If you post some sample you get code that works with that sample. I can't tell which elements you want to process in a different XML. Either try to adapt the code or ask a new question with your failed attempt, but with minimal samples to demonstrate that particular problem, not with unrelated data.

Comment: wavvv great Martin Honnen, I got the output. Thank you so much. Thanks stackoverflow.com